# Links no funcionales = etiqueta <a> de HTML

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una página web, pero tengo un bug, el cual es que los links (de la etiqueta `<a>`) no se pueden cliquear. La verdad, he estado revisando el código de arriba para abajo, pero no encuentro el problema. Dejaré el código completo de mi problema por si acaso.

He intentado mirar si era una incompatibilidad con algún elemento en el CSS, que me impedía dar click al vínculo, pero no he podido encontrar el problema.

---

Dato: si ejecutas el código en pantalla completa, el error aparece.

```css
.contenedor1{
    text-align: center;
    top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border-bottom: solid 2.5px #27216f;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.contenedor1 p{
    margin: 20px;
}
.contenedor1 a{
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor1">
                <p>Sabiendo que estas interesado en nuestros servicios, estos son los tipos de planes que te proponemos. Para mas información con los planes, tipo de facturación, etc.</p>
                <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
            </div>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
/*-----------------------------------*/
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(79, 79, 79);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: #585858;
}
/*-----------------------------------*/
#progressbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
#scrollpath{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
@keyframes animate{
    0%,100%{
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
#progressbar:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}
#progressbar::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}
/*------------------------------------------*/
body{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body.active{
    background: #121212;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
body.active p, h1,h2{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.barra_lateral{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 85px;
    background: #0A0A2A;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active{
    width: 240px;
}
body.active .barra_lateral{
    border-right: solid 5px #1d1b31;
    background: #1f1f1f;
}
.Logo{
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active .Logo{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.Logo_Name{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#Menu{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    left: 0%;
    top: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transform: translateX(+25%);
    background: #0A0A2A;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active #Menu{
    left: 90%;
}
body.active .barra_lateral.active #Menu{
    background: #1f1f1f;
    border-right: solid 5px #1d1b31;
}
body.active #Menu{
    background: #1f1f1f;
}
.barra_lateral ul{
    z-index: 90;
    position: relative;
    top: -58%;
    left: -20%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}
.barra_lateral ul li{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.barra_lateral ul li.active{
    border-bottom: solid 1.5px #ffffff;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li.active{
    border-bottom: solid 1.5px #9f9f9f;
}
.barra_lateral ul li input{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    outline: none;
    background: #1d1b31;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li input{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
}
body.active .barra_lateral.active ul li input{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: solid 4px #1d1b31;
}
.barra_lateral ul li input, .barra_lateral.active ul li input{
    background: #000;
}
.Nombre_Links{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active .Nombre_Links{
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
}
.barra_lateral ul li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li a{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover{
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
    pointer-events: all;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background: #ffffff;
}
body.active .barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover{
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
    pointer-events: all;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000;
}
.barra_lateral ul li a i{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 60px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover i{
    text-shadow: -5px -5px rgba(46, 0, 111, 0.453);
}
.Contenido_Perfil{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.Perfil{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 6px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #1d1b31;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
body.active .Perfil{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #000;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.Detalles_Perfil{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.barra_lateral.active .Detalles_Perfil{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
.Imagen_Perfil{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.Nombre_Trabajo{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.Nombre{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.Trabajo{
    font-size: 12px;
}
#toggle{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 65px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#toggle.active{
    background: #585858;
}
#toggle.active .Indicador{
    left: 35px;
    background: linear-gradient(#2E64FE,#A4A4A4);
}
.Indicador{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFF00,#ffaf01);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    border-radius: 15px;
}
/*-------Código del Contenido---------*/
.Contenido{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.Contenido.active{
    width: 88.5%;
}
.Logo_Imagen{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #1d1b31;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
body.active .Logo_Imagen{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #1f1f1f;
}
.Logo_Imagen img{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
body.active .Logo_Imagen img{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #ffffff82;
}
.contenedor1{
    text-align: center;
    top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border-bottom: solid 2.5px #27216f;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
body.active .contenedor1{
    border-bottom: solid 4px rgb(79, 79, 79);
}
.contenedor1 img{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.contenedor1 #diseño{
    position: relative;
    transition: all 10s ease;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contenedor1 h1{
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px;
}
.contenedor1 p{
    margin: 20px;
}
.contenedor1 .textual{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
body.active .contenedor1 h1{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color: #fff;
}
body.active .contenedor1{
    background: #ffffff85;
}
.contenedor1.active{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    margin-left: 180px;
    display: flex;
}



/*----------------------Footer---------------------*/
.main-content{
    border-top: solid 5px #8c8c8c;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #111;
    margin-left: 6.5%;
    transition: 0.01s;
}
.caja{
    text-align: center;
}
.caja h2{
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #232387;
    border-left: solid 5px rgb(91, 91, 91);
}
.izquierda{
    width: 30.5%;
    margin: 1%;
}
.central{
    width: 30.5%;
    margin: 1%;
}
.derecha{
    margin: 1%;
    width: 30.5%;
}
.izquierda .content p{
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.izquierda .content div{
    float: left;
}
.izquierda .content{
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.central .content .bx{
    font-size: 1.4375rem;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    height: 40px;
    width: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #ffffff;
    align-items: center;
}
.central .content .bx:hover{
    background: #151555;
}
.central .content .texto{
    font-size: 1.0625rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.central .content .phone{
    margin: 10px 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.derecha .contactanos .boton{
    margin: 10px;
}
.derecha .contactanos .boton button{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1.0625rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.derecha .contactanos .boton p{
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 80%;
}
.Contenido.active .derecha .contactanos .boton button{
    width: 75%;
}
.derecha .contactanos .boton button:hover{
    background: #151555;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" charset="utf-8">
        <title>NewSpace | Inicio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS's/NewSpaceServicios.css">
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    </head>
    <body>
<!---------------------------Código Barra Lateral------------------------------>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <div id="scrollpath"></div>
        <nav class="Barra_Navegacion">
            <div class="barra_lateral">
                <div class="Contenido_Logo">
                    <div class="Logo">
                        <div class="Logo_Name">Navegación</div>
                    </div>
                    <i class='bx bx-menu' id="Menu"></i>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Búsqueda...">
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Inicio.html">
                            <i class='bx bxs-home' id="Inicio"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Inicio</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Servicios.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-bolt-circle' id="Servicios"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Servicios</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Novedades.html">
                            <i class='bx bxs-news' id="Novedades"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Novedades</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Terminos.html">
                            <i class='bx bxs-file-doc' id="Terminos"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Términos</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Contacto.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-phone' id="Contacto"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Contacto</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Soporte.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-wrench' id="Soporte"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Soporte</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="toggle">
                        <i class="Indicador"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="Contenido_Perfil">
                    <div class="Perfil">
                        <div class="Detalles_Perfil">
                            <img src="/Imagenes/20210702_105012_4.jpg" alt="Desarrollador de la Pagina" class="Imagen_Perfil">
                            <div class="Nombre_Trabajo">
                                <div class="Nombre">Joan Cardozo</div>
                                <div class="Trabajo">Web Developer</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
<!-----------------------        Contenido       ---------------------------->
        <div class="Contenido">
            <div class="Logo_Imagen">
                <img src="/Imagenes/NewSpace NewNew!!!!.png" alt="NewSpace" width="190px" height="70px">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor1">
                <h1 class="presentaciontexto"><-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICIOS DE NEWSPACE &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-></h1>
                <br>
                <img src="/Imagenes/36185-animation-about-seo-dashboard.gif" alt="NewSpace - Logo" width="350‬px" height="250px">
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="contenedor1">
                <p>Sabiendo que estas interesado en nuestros servicios, estos son los tipos de planes que te proponemos. Para mas información con los planes, tipo de facturación, etc.</p>
                <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor1">
                <p class="textual">Enfocándonos en el desarrollo web, a principios del 2021, para dar calidad en el desarrollo de las paginas, con una accesibilidad y entendimiento de las misma de manera sencilla y fácil de comprender. siendo NewSpace LTDA dedicada a ayudar a la web, a evolucionar. Teniendo a nuestro nuevos y antiguos usuario para mejorar la misma.</p>
                <img  id="diseño" src="/Imagenes/webdesing.gif" alt="diseño web">
            </div>
<!-----------------------Footer o pie de Pagina------------------------>
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="caja izquierda">
                    <h2>&nbsp; Sobre Nosotros</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>Empresa Enfocada al Desarrollo Web, la cual se apoya de la comunidad.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caja central">
                    <h2>&nbsp; Dirección</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="phone">
                            <span class="bx bxs-phone-call"></span>
                            <span class="texto">+57 322 4004147</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="email">
                            <span class="bx bx-mail-send"></span>
                            <span class="texto">pintogamer64@gmail.com</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caja derecha">
                    <div class="contactanos">
                        <div class="boton">
                            <button>Contactarnos</button>
                            <p>Si nos quieres contactar, usa este botón para ir al formulario de contacto.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-------------Vinculo de JavaScript---------------->
        <script src="/JavaScript's/NewSpace.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En tu `css` a la etiqueta `body` sácale la altura que le asignaste `min-height: 100vh;`. Suerte!

Comment: muchas gracias por ayudarme a encontrar el error. @Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema efectivamente está en los `z-index`. Si te fijás en el css, a `.Contenido` le asignaste *-1* (probablemente para situarlo detrás de `.barra_lateral`), y el `div` de clase `.contenedor1` se sitúa *dentro* del `div` con la clase que mencioné al principio.

Al haber colocado un valor negativo al `z-index`, es como que se haya colocado una *barrera invisible* delante de ese contenido (analogía en base al que ha hecho @Simon Trichereau en [esta respuesta en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54148407)).

Es importante entender en este caso [el contexto de apilamiento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) (énfasis mío):

> Los elementos HTML ocupan este espacio **por orden de prioridad** basado en sus atributos.

Entonces, lo que se puede hacer es:

- agregar `z-index:2` a `.barra_lateral`.
- reemplazar `z-index:-1` por `z-index:1` en `.Contenido`.

quedando de la siguiente manera:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


/*-----------------------------------*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(79, 79, 79);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: #585858;
}


/*-----------------------------------*/

#progressbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

#scrollpath {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#progressbar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
  filter: blur(30px);
}

#progressbar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
  filter: blur(30px);
}


/*------------------------------------------*/

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body.active {
  background: #121212;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body.active p,
h1,
h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.barra_lateral {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2; /*-<---*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85px;
  background: #0A0A2A;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.barra_lateral.active {
  width: 240px;
}

body.active .barra_lateral {
  border-right: solid 5px #1d1b31;
  background: #1f1f1f;
}

.Logo {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.barra_lateral.active .Logo {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.Logo_Name {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#Menu {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0%;
  top: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  transform: translateX(+25%);
  background: #0A0A2A;
  transition: all 0.45s ease;
}

.barra_lateral.active #Menu {
  left: 90%;
}

body.active .barra_lateral.active #Menu {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  border-right: solid 5px #1d1b31;
}

body.active #Menu {
  background: #1f1f1f;
}

.barra_lateral ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
  top: -58%;
  left: -20%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.barra_lateral.active ul {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}

.barra_lateral ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.barra_lateral ul li.active {
  border-bottom: solid 1.5px #ffffff;
}

.barra_lateral.active ul li.active {
  border-bottom: solid 1.5px #9f9f9f;
}

.barra_lateral ul li input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  outline: none;
  background: #1d1b31;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.barra_lateral.active ul li input {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
}

body.active .barra_lateral.active ul li input {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border: solid 4px #1d1b31;
}

.barra_lateral ul li input,
.barra_lateral.active ul li input {
  background: #000;
}

.Nombre_Links {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.05s ease;
}

.barra_lateral.active .Nombre_Links {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.05s ease;
}

.barra_lateral ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.05s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.barra_lateral.active ul li a {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover {
  transition: all 0.05s ease;
  pointer-events: all;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  background: #ffffff;
}

body.active .barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover {
  transition: all 0.05s ease;
  pointer-events: all;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000;
}

.barra_lateral ul li a i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 60px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover i {
  text-shadow: -5px -5px rgba(46, 0, 111, 0.453);
}

.Contenido_Perfil {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.Perfil {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 6px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

body.active .Perfil {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #000;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.Detalles_Perfil {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.barra_lateral.active .Detalles_Perfil {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.Imagen_Perfil {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Nombre_Trabajo {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.Nombre {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.Trabajo {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#toggle {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 65px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle.active {
  background: #585858;
}

#toggle.active .Indicador {
  left: 35px;
  background: linear-gradient(#2E64FE, #A4A4A4);
}

.Indicador {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFFF00, #ffaf01);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/*-------Código del Contenido---------*/

.Contenido {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: 1; /*-<---*/
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.Contenido.active {
  width: 88.5%;
}

.Logo_Imagen {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #1d1b31;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body.active .Logo_Imagen {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #1f1f1f;
}

.Logo_Imagen img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body.active .Logo_Imagen img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #ffffff82;
}

.contenedor1 {
  text-align: center;
  top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 180px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-bottom: solid 2.5px #27216f;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body.active .contenedor1 {
  border-bottom: solid 4px rgb(79, 79, 79);
}

.contenedor1 img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contenedor1 #diseño {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 10s ease;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contenedor1 h1 {
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}

.contenedor1 p {
  margin: 20px;
}

.contenedor1 .textual {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

body.active .contenedor1 h1 {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #fff;
}

body.active .contenedor1 {
  background: #ffffff85;
}

.contenedor1.active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-left: 180px;
  display: flex;
}


/*----------------------Footer---------------------*/

.main-content {
  border-top: solid 5px #8c8c8c;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #111;
  margin-left: 6.5%;
  transition: 0.01s;
}

.caja {
  text-align: center;
}

.caja h2 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #232387;
  border-left: solid 5px rgb(91, 91, 91);
}

.izquierda {
  width: 30.5%;
  margin: 1%;
}

.central {
  width: 30.5%;
  margin: 1%;
}

.derecha {
  margin: 1%;
  width: 30.5%;
}

.izquierda .content p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.izquierda .content div {
  float: left;
}

.izquierda .content {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.central .content .bx {
  font-size: 1.4375rem;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  height: 40px;
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: #ffffff;
  align-items: center;
}

.central .content .bx:hover {
  background: #151555;
}

.central .content .texto {
  font-size: 1.0625rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.central .content .phone {
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.derecha .contactanos .boton {
  margin: 10px;
}

.derecha .contactanos .boton button {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.0625rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.derecha .contactanos .boton p {
  text-align: right;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80%;
}

.Contenido.active .derecha .contactanos .boton button {
  width: 75%;
}

.derecha .contactanos .boton button:hover {
  background: #151555;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" charset="utf-8">
  <title>NewSpace | Inicio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS's/NewSpaceServicios.css">
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <!---------------------------Código Barra Lateral------------------------------>
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
  <div id="scrollpath"></div>
  <nav class="Barra_Navegacion">
    <div class="barra_lateral">
      <div class="Contenido_Logo">
        <div class="Logo">
          <div class="Logo_Name">Navegación</div>
        </div>
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="Menu"></i>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Búsqueda...">
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="NewSpace_Inicio.html">
            <i class='bx bxs-home' id="Inicio"></i>
            <span class="Nombre_Links">Inicio</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="NewSpace_Servicios.html">
            <i class='bx bx-bolt-circle' id="Servicios"></i>
            <span class="Nombre_Links">Servicios</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="NewSpace_Novedades.html">
            <i class='bx bxs-news' id="Novedades"></i>
            <span class="Nombre_Links">Novedades</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="NewSpace_Terminos.html">
            <i class='bx bxs-file-doc' id="Terminos"></i>
            <span class="Nombre_Links">Términos</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="NewSpace_Contacto.html">
            <i class='bx bx-phone' id="Contacto"></i>
            <span class="Nombre_Links">Contacto</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="NewSpace_Soporte.html">
            <i class='bx bx-wrench' id="Soporte"></i>
            <span class="Nombre_Links">Soporte</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="toggle">
          <i class="Indicador"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="Contenido_Perfil">
        <div class="Perfil">
          <div class="Detalles_Perfil">
            <img src="/Imagenes/20210702_105012_4.jpg" alt="Desarrollador de la Pagina" class="Imagen_Perfil">
            <div class="Nombre_Trabajo">
              <div class="Nombre">Joan Cardozo</div>
              <div class="Trabajo">Web Developer</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-----------------------        Contenido       ---------------------------->
  <div class="Contenido">
    <div class="Logo_Imagen">
      <img src="/Imagenes/NewSpace NewNew!!!!.png" alt="NewSpace" width="190px" height="70px">
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor1">
      <h1 class="presentaciontexto">&lt;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICIOS DE NEWSPACE &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&gt;</h1>
      <br>
      <img src="/Imagenes/36185-animation-about-seo-dashboard.gif" alt="NewSpace - Logo" width="350‬px" height="250px">
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="contenedor1">
      <p>Sabiendo que estas interesado en nuestros servicios, estos son los tipos de planes que te proponemos. Para mas información con los planes, tipo de facturación, etc.</p>
      <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor1">
      <p class="textual">Enfocándonos en el desarrollo web, a principios del 2021, para dar calidad en el desarrollo de las paginas, con una accesibilidad y entendimiento de las misma de manera sencilla y fácil de comprender. siendo NewSpace LTDA dedicada a ayudar a la
        web, a evolucionar. Teniendo a nuestro nuevos y antiguos usuario para mejorar la misma.</p>
      <img id="diseño" src="/Imagenes/webdesing.gif" alt="diseño web">
    </div>
    <!-----------------------Footer o pie de Pagina------------------------>
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="caja izquierda">
        <h2>&nbsp; Sobre Nosotros</h2>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Empresa Enfocada al Desarrollo Web, la cual se apoya de la comunidad.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="caja central">
        <h2>&nbsp; Dirección</h2>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="phone">
            <span class="bx bxs-phone-call"></span>
            <span class="texto">+57 322 4004147</span>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <span class="bx bx-mail-send"></span>
            <span class="texto">pintogamer64@gmail.com</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="caja derecha">
        <div class="contactanos">
          <div class="boton">
            <button>Contactarnos</button>
            <p>Si nos quieres contactar, usa este botón para ir al formulario de contacto.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-------------Vinculo de JavaScript---------------->
  <script src="/JavaScript's/NewSpace.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

<sub>- En realidad, si te fijás, el *bug* también se presenta en el botón *Contactarnos*. Es bastante particular porque solo se puede reproducir en pantallas "grandes".</sub> 
<sub>- Como nota adicional, hice unos cambios en la sección de texto donde se presentan las "flechas" `< -` `- >` Reemplacé `<` por `&lt;` y `>` por `&gt;`, para evitar conflictos con las etiquetas de html.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Por algún motivo el body ha quedado superpuesto sobre todo lo demás. No he encontrado porqué pero la solución apeñuscada es añadir `z-index:1;`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
/*-----------------------------------*/
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(79, 79, 79);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: #585858;
}
/*-----------------------------------*/
#progressbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
#scrollpath{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
@keyframes animate{
    0%,100%{
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
#progressbar:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}
#progressbar::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}
/*------------------------------------------*/
body{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
body.active{
    background: #121212;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
body.active p, h1,h2{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.barra_lateral{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 85px;
    background: #0A0A2A;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active{
    width: 240px;
}
body.active .barra_lateral{
    border-right: solid 5px #1d1b31;
    background: #1f1f1f;
}
.Logo{
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active .Logo{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.Logo_Name{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#Menu{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    left: 0%;
    top: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transform: translateX(+25%);
    background: #0A0A2A;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active #Menu{
    left: 90%;
}
body.active .barra_lateral.active #Menu{
    background: #1f1f1f;
    border-right: solid 5px #1d1b31;
}
body.active #Menu{
    background: #1f1f1f;
}
.barra_lateral ul{
    z-index: 90;
    position: relative;
    top: -58%;
    left: -20%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}
.barra_lateral ul li{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.barra_lateral ul li.active{
    border-bottom: solid 1.5px #ffffff;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li.active{
    border-bottom: solid 1.5px #9f9f9f;
}
.barra_lateral ul li input{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    outline: none;
    background: #1d1b31;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li input{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
}
body.active .barra_lateral.active ul li input{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: solid 4px #1d1b31;
}
.barra_lateral ul li input, .barra_lateral.active ul li input{
    background: #000;
}
.Nombre_Links{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
}
.barra_lateral.active .Nombre_Links{
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
}
.barra_lateral ul li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li a{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover{
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
    pointer-events: all;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background: #ffffff;
}
body.active .barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover{
    transition: all 0.05s ease;
    pointer-events: all;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000;
}
.barra_lateral ul li a i{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 60px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.barra_lateral.active ul li a:hover i{
    text-shadow: -5px -5px rgba(46, 0, 111, 0.453);
}
.Contenido_Perfil{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.Perfil{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 6px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #1d1b31;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
body.active .Perfil{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #000;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.Detalles_Perfil{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.barra_lateral.active .Detalles_Perfil{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
.Imagen_Perfil{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.Nombre_Trabajo{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.Nombre{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.Trabajo{
    font-size: 12px;
}
#toggle{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 65px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#toggle.active{
    background: #585858;
}
#toggle.active .Indicador{
    left: 35px;
    background: linear-gradient(#2E64FE,#A4A4A4);
}
.Indicador{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFF00,#ffaf01);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    border-radius: 15px;
}
/*-------Código del Contenido---------*/
.Contenido{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.Contenido.active{
    width: 88.5%;
}
.Logo_Imagen{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #1d1b31;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
body.active .Logo_Imagen{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #1f1f1f;
}
.Logo_Imagen img{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
body.active .Logo_Imagen img{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #ffffff82;
}
.contenedor1{
    text-align: center;
    top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border-bottom: solid 2.5px #27216f;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
body.active .contenedor1{
    border-bottom: solid 4px rgb(79, 79, 79);
}
.contenedor1 img{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.contenedor1 #diseño{
    position: relative;
    transition: all 10s ease;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contenedor1 h1{
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px;
}
.contenedor1 p{
    margin: 20px;
}
.contenedor1 .textual{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
body.active .contenedor1 h1{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color: #fff;
}
body.active .contenedor1{
    background: #ffffff85;
}
.contenedor1.active{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    margin-left: 180px;
    display: flex;
}



/*----------------------Footer---------------------*/
.main-content{
    border-top: solid 5px #8c8c8c;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #111;
    margin-left: 6.5%;
    transition: 0.01s;
}
.caja{
    text-align: center;
}
.caja h2{
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #232387;
    border-left: solid 5px rgb(91, 91, 91);
}
.izquierda{
    width: 30.5%;
    margin: 1%;
}
.central{
    width: 30.5%;
    margin: 1%;
}
.derecha{
    margin: 1%;
    width: 30.5%;
}
.izquierda .content p{
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.izquierda .content div{
    float: left;
}
.izquierda .content{
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.central .content .bx{
    font-size: 1.4375rem;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    height: 40px;
    width: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #ffffff;
    align-items: center;
}
.central .content .bx:hover{
    background: #151555;
}
.central .content .texto{
    font-size: 1.0625rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.central .content .phone{
    margin: 10px 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.derecha .contactanos .boton{
    margin: 10px;
}
.derecha .contactanos .boton button{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1.0625rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.derecha .contactanos .boton p{
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 80%;
}
.Contenido.active .derecha .contactanos .boton button{
    width: 75%;
}
.derecha .contactanos .boton button:hover{
    background: #151555;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" charset="utf-8">
        <title>NewSpace | Inicio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS's/NewSpaceServicios.css">
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    </head>
    <body>
<!---------------------------Código Barra Lateral------------------------------>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <div id="scrollpath"></div>
        <nav class="Barra_Navegacion">
            <div class="barra_lateral">
                <div class="Contenido_Logo">
                    <div class="Logo">
                        <div class="Logo_Name">Navegación</div>
                    </div>
                    <i class='bx bx-menu' id="Menu"></i>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Búsqueda...">
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Inicio.html">
                            <i class='bx bxs-home' id="Inicio"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Inicio</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Servicios.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-bolt-circle' id="Servicios"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Servicios</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Novedades.html">
                            <i class='bx bxs-news' id="Novedades"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Novedades</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Terminos.html">
                            <i class='bx bxs-file-doc' id="Terminos"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Términos</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Contacto.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-phone' id="Contacto"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Contacto</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="NewSpace_Soporte.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-wrench' id="Soporte"></i>
                            <span class="Nombre_Links">Soporte</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="toggle">
                        <i class="Indicador"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="Contenido_Perfil">
                    <div class="Perfil">
                        <div class="Detalles_Perfil">
                            <img src="/Imagenes/20210702_105012_4.jpg" alt="Desarrollador de la Pagina" class="Imagen_Perfil">
                            <div class="Nombre_Trabajo">
                                <div class="Nombre">Joan Cardozo</div>
                                <div class="Trabajo">Web Developer</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
<!-----------------------        Contenido       ---------------------------->
        <div class="Contenido">
            <div class="Logo_Imagen">
                <img src="/Imagenes/NewSpace NewNew!!!!.png" alt="NewSpace" width="190px" height="70px">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor1">
                <h1 class="presentaciontexto"><-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICIOS DE NEWSPACE &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-></h1>
                <br>
                <img src="/Imagenes/36185-animation-about-seo-dashboard.gif" alt="NewSpace - Logo" width="350‬px" height="250px">
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div class="contenedor1">
                <p>Sabiendo que estas interesado en nuestros servicios, estos son los tipos de planes que te proponemos. Para mas información con los planes, tipo de facturación, etc.</p>
                <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor1">
                <p class="textual">Enfocándonos en el desarrollo web, a principios del 2021, para dar calidad en el desarrollo de las paginas, con una accesibilidad y entendimiento de las misma de manera sencilla y fácil de comprender. siendo NewSpace LTDA dedicada a ayudar a la web, a evolucionar. Teniendo a nuestro nuevos y antiguos usuario para mejorar la misma.</p>
                <img  id="diseño" src="/Imagenes/webdesing.gif" alt="diseño web">
            </div>
<!-----------------------Footer o pie de Pagina------------------------>
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="caja izquierda">
                    <h2>&nbsp; Sobre Nosotros</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>Empresa Enfocada al Desarrollo Web, la cual se apoya de la comunidad.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caja central">
                    <h2>&nbsp; Dirección</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="phone">
                            <span class="bx bxs-phone-call"></span>
                            <span class="texto">+57 322 4004147</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="email">
                            <span class="bx bx-mail-send"></span>
                            <span class="texto">pintogamer64@gmail.com</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caja derecha">
                    <div class="contactanos">
                        <div class="boton">
                            <button>Contactarnos</button>
                            <p>Si nos quieres contactar, usa este botón para ir al formulario de contacto.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-------------Vinculo de JavaScript---------------->
        <script src="/JavaScript's/NewSpace.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```